# Jmeter and Graphs Generator

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I read (maybe not so carefully) the following [link](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) and [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/BkFya7NCkp0) but despite my efforts, i can't succeed to generate my graphs.
(windows or mac).
I do have two scripts (as advised by Vincent DABURON). 
Sorry but i have a french version of Jmeter, i can switch to an english one if needed.

**Preliminaries :**

- /bin/user.properties has been updated.
- jmeter version is 3.0 r1743807

**1. FIRST SCRIPT : Measuring simple HTTP request**

[image: Script 1]

a. First one contains credentials to be given to IP, IP adress to test and a pause.

b. It is executed in non_gui mode with

```
jmeter -t myscript.jmx -n -l f:\data\jmeter\test-results.csv -JTEST_RESULTS_FILE=f:\data\jmeter\test-results.csv
```

c. I do have a csv file populated with the following (extract)

> timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;threadName;success;bytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname;IdleTime
>   10:24:10;302;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe d'unités
>   1-1;true;266;1;1;302;1;0;MYPC;0 10:24:11;182;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe
>   d'unités 1-1;true;266;1;1;181;1;0;MYPC;0
>   10:24:12;153;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe d'unités
>   1-1;true;266;1;1;153;1;0;MYPC;0 10:24:13;198;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe
>   d'unités 1-1;true;266;1;1;198;1;0;MYPC;0

**2. SECOND SCRIPT : Generate graphs** ( Saved in bin folder as jpgx.jmx )

[image: Script 2]

a. directly under test plan, i have created a jp@gc - Graphs Generator.

```
- JMeter Results File : **${__P(TEST_RESULTS_FILE,f:\\data\\jmeter\\test-results.csv)}**

- filePrefix :  PREFIX_
```

b. Running in console

```
jmeter -t jpgc.jmx -n
```

c. I don't have any images at all.

May someone guide me on what's wrong with it ?

Kind regards,

Pierre LAURENT

Answer (score 0):

I have switch to a more recent technology ( JMeter / Influxdb / Grafana ) as perfectly described in this [link](http://www.seleniumtests.com/2015/12/real-time-jmeter-result-using-backend.html). 
Regards,
Pierre